# How to make a form align to the edge of the screen like the taskbar?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-xe2, toolbar

I'm building a "dashboard" application which is always visible along any edge of any given monitor, even when other applications are maximized. I don't necessarily need it "always on top" (although I will) but I need to make it a part of the screen as my own desktop toolbar, like the Windows Taskbar is. Even when applications are maximized, the windows are inside of this area, making this window always visible (and the desktop area smaller).

How can I make my application's main form align to the edge of a screen like this?

PS - I don't need an answer to all the extra gritty handling, such as screen resolution changes... I just need to know how to make it aligned as "part of the screen" in the first place.

Comment: Read the work area to find the edge of the screen and put your form there

Comment: @David I'm asking how to treat it like the Windows Taskbar, not just how to put it there. That's the easy part. The hard part is making it "a part of the screen" as I say twice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [Application Desktop Toolbars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is what the Windows task bar uses internally. It involves creating a window with specific styles, setting it up correctly, and then communicating with it using [`SHAppBarMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It can get pretty complex, but there are some free components available with source (one at [Torry](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=19), or another at [DelphiPages](http://www.delphipages.com/comp/tappbar-3864.html)) that have the basic shell to get you started.

An example from the `AppBar.pas` unit of the second link (which, according to the link's text, is freeware with source - I've used it to create an app launcher task bar, complete with buttons with application icons and descriptions read from `.lnk` files):

```
type
  TAppBarMessage = (abmNew, abmRemove, abmQueryPos, abmSetPos, abmGetState, 
                    abmGetTaskBarPos, abmActivate, abmGetAutoHideBar, 
                    abmSetAutoHideBar, abmWindowPosChanged);

  TAppBarEdge = (abeLeft, abeTop, abeRight, abeBottom, abeUnknown, abeFloat);

...

function TAppBar.AppBarMessage(abMessage: TAppBarMessage; 
  abEdge: TAppBarEdge; lParam: LPARAM; bRect: Boolean; var rc: TRect): UINT;
var
  abd: TAppBarData;
begin
  // Initialize an APPBARDATA structure
  abd.cbSize := sizeof(abd);
  abd.hWnd := Handle;
  abd.uCallbackMessage := WM_APPBARNOTIFY;
  abd.uEdge := Ord(abEdge);

  if bRect then
    abd.rc := rc
  else
    abd.rc := Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);

  abd.lParam := lParam;
  Result := SHAppBarMessage(Ord(abMessage), abd);

  // If the caller passed a rectangle, return the updated rectangle
  if bRect then
    rc := abd.rc;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's extremely easy to use and saves a lot of headache!

Comment: Unfortunately it's not letting me drag it over to another monitor :( It still does the trick though

Comment: Sorry. :-( Can't help with that part. We switched to Win2K8 as our server OS, and group policies let us push out a folder full of links to the apps that get added to the `Start` menu, so I haven't done anything with regard to supporting multiple monitors - only coders had them then, and we didn't use the app launcher. :-)

Comment: I can still play with the source and figure it out :D

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, you can determine this information manually.  Have a look at the global `Screen` object in the `Forms` unit for information on the current resolution. (Make sure to check the `MonitorCount` and `Monitors` properties.)

Between that and a bit of basic arithmetic, it shouldn't be too hard to set up the form to align to the edge of a monitor.

Comment: Thanks, but that's the easy part that I don't need help with. Refer to Ken's answer.